# Selected Multiple Dropdown in Codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter-4

How to select multiple dropdown in edit page in Codeigniter 4?
I want to use in_array() method but did not found how to get the array from its controller.

```
    public function edit($id)
    {

        $data = [
            'brand' => $this->brands->find($id),
            'groups' => $this->groups->findAll(),
            'listbrands' => $this->listbrands->where('brand_id', $id)->findAll(),
        ];

        return view('brands/edit', $data);
    }
```

the key is in listbrands which contain

```
group_id | brand_id
---------+---------
150      | 1
150      | 2
```

and this is my view

```
<div class="form-group">
    <?= form_label('Group Type:', 'group_id') ?>
    <select class=" form-control select2" id="group_id" name="group_id[]" multiple>
        <?php foreach ($groups as $group) : ?>
            <option <?= in_array($group['id'], $listbrands) ? 'selected' : '' ?> value="<?= $group['id'] ?>"><?= $group['name'] ?></option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Can I ask why are you not using the `form_dropdown` helper? This will save you a fair chunk of coding and may also fix your issue.

Comment: I have use it for Input text, but when there is no value for ```old('textname')``` in validation, the page showing me error. So that I am afraid of using form helper input